# iOSSimulatorのHardwareKeyboardの認識が101キーボードになっている？

Tags: ios, xcode

iOSSimualtorでHardwareKeyboardを使った場合に、画面のUITextFieldなどに`@`を入力すると、`[`が入力されます。今は`Shift+2`でしのいでいますが、直す方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますか？

- iOSSimulatorのハードウェアキーボードの英語のところは自動
- 言語は日本語
- 地域は日本

になっています。

OSX 10.11.6
Xcode8.0
Simulator iPhone 6s - iOS 10.0
日本語キーボードのMacBookAir

いつからこうなったのかはわかりません。Xcode7からこうだったのかも。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
「キーボード」-「新しいキーボードを追加」で「英語(日本)」を追加する。
これだと106なんですね。